# What does arr[i],i mean?

Tags: c++, c, process

I came across a code with following condition

```
(number[i],i)<(number[j],j)
```

Can someone tell what does this condition mean or checks?

i,j are variables and number is array

Here is the whole code-

```
do{
    choosing[i]=true;
    number[i]=max(mumber[0],number[1],...,number[n-1])+1;
    choosing[i]=false;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    while(choosing[j]);
    while((number[j]!=0)&&(number[j],j)<(number[i],i));}
```

critical section

```
number[i]=0;}while(1);
```

It was a critical section problem in multiple processes.
Initialisations-

```
bool choosing[n];
int number[n];
```

This is what the book wrote about the condition-

Comment: Read about the *comma* operator. Though it's not clear to me what motivated the author to write this code.

Comment: It's equivalent to `i < j`. I can't think of any good reason to have the array references in there, except to obfuscate the code.

Comment: What kind of code was that?

Comment: It was a multiple process solution code

Comment: Although this question is technically answered by explaining the comma operator, I doubt that will satisfy the OP, since he will still be wondering what the point of this code is (as we all are).

Comment: If it is C++ code, then it is possible that the class of `number` overrides the `[]` operator.  In that event, the `number[i]` and `number[j]` could have a *bona fide* useful purpose, for some value of "useful".

Comment: For that matter, I guess the comma operator could be overridden, too.  (snarky comment suppressed.)

Comment: It could be an odd attempt at bounds checking i and j by trying to force a bad-access if either is greater than the length of number

Comment: @monster could you post the relevant parts of the code, that is the code around `(number[i],i)<(number[j],j)` and the declaration of `number`. And please tell us if it's C or C++. The answer you will possibly get depends on that.

Comment: @monster quoting you: _i and j are variables and number is array_ : variables of what type, and an array of what? (yes, the answer may also depend on this).

Comment: Yep.. given the update this code makes a little sense.

Comment: BTW, this looks like a part of some multithreaded or otherwise concurrent code (given it is polling some seemingly non-changing variable `choosing[j]`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. still not sure about the actual purpose of `(number[i],i)` .

Comment: @MichaelWalz Looks to me like some dirty WA for some obscure problem like caching and/or optimization, forcing the compiler to spit out some "working" sequence.

Comment: @monster what kind of software is this running on what kind of hardware?

Comment: It was actually in my book of Operating System Concepts i have attached the page writing about the condition  in question

Comment: @monster _i have attached the page writing about the condition in question_: no you haven't, check your question.